# Directly install Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit on SSD: what are prerequisites

Tags: pi-4, 64-bit, pi4-eeprom

To install a 64-bit Raspberry OS on a Pi 4 board can be achieved by

- download the zip file from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2020-08-24/)
- unzip and write content to empty SSD  as you would for an SD card, gives two partions (a FAT boot and a EXT4 rootfs)
- connect the SSD to the RPi4 (e.g. put the SSD in an USB3.0 enclosure and connect to the USB3 ports of the RPi4)
- remove any card in the card slot of the RPi4!
- power on, wait a minute, system reboots, wait another couple of minutes, then answer the setup questions.

This gives, with some luck, a fast running RPI4 with a very large `rootfs` partition to fill the SSD. Installation of XFCE4 speeds things further up!

Questions:

- Why would the approach sometimes fail and has to repeated? In my experience, success after 1 or 2 trials.
- When is a update of the rpi-eeprom necessary? is this automatically done when a full-upgrade is done?
- Is it necessary to enable the USB boot? It can be done - on a running RPi4 with `raspi-config`.

Comment: works with #ASM1153E SATA 6gb/s bridge" from ASMedia Technology (ID 174c:55aa) but does not work reliable with ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp.  JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge. Perhaps the firmware update "https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/45588-tip-firmwareupdate-fuer-usb3-0-sata-adapter-152d-0578/" would help.